# if there error like this, what I have to code to improve it

Tags: java, palindrome

The error is like this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 9
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:658)
    at palindrom.Palindrom.main(Palindrom.java:30)

Comment: the first character of a string is at index 0. So, someString.charAt(9) crashes with that error if the string has 9 or fewer characters (if you want the very last character of a 9-sized string, ti's .charAt(8) - because we start the count at 0).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to compare the index and the string length before calling charAt().

```
public static void main() {
    String str = "hello";
    int index = 9;
    if (index < str.length()) {
        char c = str.charAt(index);
    }
}
```